# How racially diverse is the Dominion?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

To memory, in *[Star Trek: Deep Space 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)*, we only see three races from the [Dominion](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dominion):

- The [Jem'Hadar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jem%27Hadar)
- The [Founders](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Founder)
- The [Vorta](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vorta)

What other races exist within it?

Comment: The longer you vatch ds9 diverse it gets.

Comment: Well there's everybody they've conquered by force...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't really get a lot of info about the Dominion in DS9. The fact that it's intended to be *powerful and enigmatic* doesn't really lend itself to us getting a close analysis of its composition and population.

We do know about six races that exist as part of the Dominion in the Gamma Quadrant;

- [Karemma](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Karemma)
- [T-Rogorans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T-Rogoran)
- [Yaderans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yaderan)
- [Vorta](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vorta)
- [Jem'Hadar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jem%27Hadar)
- [Dosi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dosi) (who may or may not be *full* members of the Dominion)

Additionally, over the series the Dominion grows to include several Alpha Quadrant species including the [Cardassians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cardassian) and the [Breen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Breen_Confederacy).

---

Other species mentioned in lower canon works included the [Rindamil](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Rindamil), [Overne](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Overne), [Thepnossen](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Thepnossen) and [Ourentia](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Ourentia)